# Excel: Is there information on how to create web query service in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

In Excel, there are methods to access data from external data sources. Excel comes with MSN Money Web Service which pulls data into the sheet. The sheet can refresh the data, etc.. Is there info/doc on how to develop such service ?

Comment: I think we can assume this is not about web services, but web queries.  Mike & DrDee both replied with Web Query information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for Microsoft Query syntax couple days ago myself, not for the webqueries, but for the normal ones. I was unlucky with my search, but I have found [XL97: How to Create Web Query (.iqy) Files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/157482)

**Edit**
Hmm, I have just noticed that you have a *c#* tag and you have mentioned *webservices*, so I'm not so sure if this is what you meant.

Comment: This is good. The link you have here is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would give Microsoft Office Online Help a shot at: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HA010548481033.aspx