# How I can export .xls file on IE 7 and 8

Tags: javascript, html

I need to export an .xls file from a web page that contains only a table in HTML.
Now I'm using `document.execCommand("SaveAs","true","documentname.xls");` 
but for IE 7 and IE 8 on Windows XP SP3 there is no Save As dialog popup.

I can use only HTML and JavaScript (no server side scripting) and the file extension must already be .xls for the user to save it. (The user cannot change the file extension later).

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I export tables to excel from a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5524143/62576).

Comment: The How can I export tables to excel from a webpage. is excute excel application to save it not save to file directly form ie. i already try it but if pc does not have excel it will not work.

Comment: Um... No, it doesn't. Look at the top answer (the one with 24 upvotes and a `+100` bounty awarded). It doesn't use Excel automation at all; I wouldn't have linked it if it did.

Comment: Ok. i see it http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/ i will try thank you