# HTML Table to Excel Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, html-table

I'm trying to use this script to save a html table to an Excel file, and it works fine, however it doesn't come up in the proper name, but rather with a random string.
And I can't see why .

I call it with:

```
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('tablename', 'name')" value="Export to Excel">
```

code

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function(table, name) {
if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
}
})()
```

Comment: You are passing parameters 'name' and 'tablename' to `tableToExcel` but the function doesn't declare any parameters

Comment: do you know how to fix this? My js is not very great :P

Comment: @Yuriy Galanter - the variable `tableToExcel` is set to the return value of an unnamed function which gets executed immediately as the page loads. The return value is a reference to the anonymous function `function(table,name)`, so when you call `tableToExcel` it's really this function which gets executed.

Comment: @TimWilliams yup figured it out already, now figuring answer to the question

Answer (score 65):

You can use `download` attribute supported by modern browsera for `a` anchor element. First modify your HTML by adding an invisible anchor:

```
<a id="dlink"  style="display:none;"></a>

<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('tablename', 'name', 'myfile.xls')" value="Export to Excel">
```

Notice also that the call to function `tableToExcel` now has 3rd parameter - where you specify file name.

Now use this modified code of your original function:

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
        return function (table, name, filename) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

            document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
            document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
            document.getElementById("dlink").click();

        }
    })()
```

Notice last 3 code lines: Instead of assigning URL to window - they assign it to the new anchor, then use new `download` attribute to force download as the given file name and then simple call `click()` method of the anchor.

Give it a try.

**Update - For supporting utf-8 characters**

As per the comment below by @WorldSEnder, a simple `meta` tag in the template would make the excel support utf-8 characters like Hindi.

```
template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><meta charset="utf-8"/><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
```

Comment: Awesome! The name works, but now I'm getting this error: `The file you are trying to open, 'name.xls', is a different format than specified in the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file.`

Comment: This is normal, you should've gotten this before as well. This is happening because the file is not a real Excel, but rather XML in disguise. But after that warning the file should be opening OK anyway. You can play with file extension to try to get rid of the warning (e.g. change it to .XML  etc.)

Comment: Hi, I know this is an older post but I get an error saying Object doesn't support property or method 'btoa'.

Comment: @seroth It may not be supported in older browsers (IE9 and below). Try to include this file to add support: https://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/source/browse/trunk/javascript/base64.js?r=230

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317951/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript-jquery-is-not-working-properl/24081343#24081343

Comment: @Yuriy...Similar like this I have three tables and I want those tables to be the worksheets in the same excel file....I have tried this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/29717451/6547301](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29717451/6547301) but table styling is not retained, I want to retain the styles of the table in excel sheet

Comment: You can simply add `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` to the template where you'd expect it if you want to export utf data.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - Not working in IE10+. On clicking download link, user is redirected to `data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,PGh0bWwgeG1sbnM6bz0idXJuOnNjaGVtYXMtbWljcm9zb2Z0LWNvbTpvZmZpY2U6b2Zm..............................` and results to **404 Page Not Found** error!

Comment: i can save my excel file but it loses all numbers' decimal places like 5,1234 -> 51234 or even -> 51.234. I've tried to save as .xlsx but this time file does not open but i can preview it on macOS with the correct decimals are in place

Comment: fantastic ...great one

Comment: is it possible to text align center in excel programatically...

Answer (score 15):

The 3 code lines above doesn't work in my case, but here what I found and I hope it could help.

```js
function tableToExcel(table, name, filename) {
        let uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,', 
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><title></title><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>', 
        base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(s))) },         format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; })}
        
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        link.click();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input 
  type="button" 
  onclick="tableToExcel('myTable', 'name', 'myfile.xls')" 
  value="Export to Excel"
>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Snippet seems broken.

Comment: Sometimes, we need to encode UTF-8 for `window.btoa` to work. See [Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23223718/1287812)

Comment: Big Table cannot be Exported..! Please Help (More than 20000 records)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method.

**Keep this button wherever you want to display the Export Button**

```
<button id="btnExport" onclick="fnExcelReport('myExcelFile.xlsx');" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"> Export </button>
```

**Add these lines to the bottom of the page**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/linways/table-to-excel@v1.0.4/dist/tableToExcel.js"></script>
<script>
         function fnExcelReport(fileName) {
                    let table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
                    return TableToExcel.convert(table[0], {
                        name: fileName,
                        sheet: {
                            name: 'Sheet 1'
                        }
                    });
                }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the event of click, Change  tableToExcel function to just send a desired file name with an extention of .xlsx:

```
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('tablename.xlsx')" value="Export to Excel">
```

And the tableToExcel function can look like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/linways/table-to-excel@v1.0.4/dist/tableToExcel.js"></script>
<script>
     function tableToExcel(fileName) {
                let table = document.getElementById('table');
                return TableToExcel.convert(table, {
                    name: fileName,
                    sheet: {
                        name: 'Sheet 1'
                    }
                });
            }
</script>
```