# Format hyperlinks when exporting HTML table to Excel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm downloading HTML table contents to a Excel using JavaScript as mentioned in [Export HTML table to Excel its downloading table contents to the Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213611/export-html-table-to-excel-its-downloading-table-contents-to-the-excel).

In my table there are links in one column. When I download, that column content shows as hyperlinks in the Excel sheet. I want to export the table to Excel without those links (just plain text).

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace all the hyperlinks with text.

Clone the table that is to be exported

```
table = $('#'+tableName).clone();
```

Replace the anchor tag with corresponding span

```
 var sp1 = document.createElement("span");
 var sp1_content = document.createTextNode($(hyperLinks[i]).text());
 sp1.appendChild(sp1_content);
 var sp2 = hyperLinks[i];
 var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;
 parentDiv.replaceChild(sp1, sp2);
```

You can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) details about replacing a node.

Exported using the code from [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129220/1188938)

---

Here is the snippet or [PEN](http://codepen.io/clickdilip/pen/MwYMqp)

```js
var tmp;
function strip(html) {
  tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
  tmp.innerHTML = html;
  console.log(tmp.innerText);
  console.log(tmp.textContent);
  
  return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
}

var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name, filename) {
    if (!table.nodeType) 
    
      /*Clone the table that is to be exported*/
      table = $('#'+table).clone();
    
      
    
    var hyperLinks = table.find('a');
    
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < hyperLinks.length; i++) {
          
      //hyperLinks[i] =  $(hyperLinks[i]).text();
          var sp1 = document.createElement("span");

          // give it an id attribute called 'newSpan'
          sp1.setAttribute("id", "newSpan");

          // create some content for the new element.
          var sp1_content = document.createTextNode($(hyperLinks[i]).text());
          console.log(sp1_content);
          // apply that content to the new element
          sp1.appendChild(sp1_content);

          // build a reference to the existing node to be replaced
          var sp2 = hyperLinks[i];
          var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;

          // replace existing node sp2 with the new span element sp1
          parentDiv.replaceChild(sp1, sp2);
      }
    
    

      var ctx = {
        worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
        table: table[0].innerHTML
      }
    

    document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
    document.getElementById("dlink").click();

  }
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="dlink" style="display:none;"></a>

<table name="tablename" id="tablename" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><a href="http://google.com">google</a></td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td><a href="http://microsoft.com">microsoft</a></td>
  </tr><tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td><a href="http://amazon.com">amazon</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('tablename', 'name', 'myfile.xls')" value="Export to Excel">
```