# hyperlinks are displayed as a text after exporting table to excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I have exported an HTML table as described in this link: [Export HTML table to Excel its downloading table contents to the Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213611/export-html-table-to-excel-its-downloading-table-contents-to-the-excel)

After exporting the table as .xls all hyperlinks are displayed as a text. 
The reason for that is that I have several links in one cell, delimited but semicolon.
Is there any solution for displaying several hyperlinks(i suppose excel doesn't allow it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Excel has a built in function to display Hyperlinks

```
var field = '=HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com","Click for Google")';
```

The only trouble you might have is that for any downloaded file, the file will open in **Protected View** and the link might still not work.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I see now that  hyperlinks are displayed as a text because there are more than one link inside a cell