# how to convert jpeg string to base64

Tags: javascript, angular, base64, jpeg

I'm getting the below data which is a jpeg image in response body.
Below is a screen shot of the response.

[Screenshot of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36QMi.png)

[Screenshot of response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atgHr.png)

When i do type of res._body, it is a string.
How can i convert it base64 string so I can render the image in browser, or is there an easier/another way to solve this. This is a part of angular app I'm building.

Comment: `<img src="path_to_server">` might do.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code snippet

```
 convertToBase64 (binaryString) {

                    this.base64textString= btoa(binaryString);
                    console.log(base64textString);
            }
```

**Update**

If you have UTF8 check out following thread

[Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223718/failed-to-execute-btoa-on-window-the-string-to-be-encoded-contains-characte)

Comment: this didn't work, I'm getting "Error DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range."

Comment: @Mukund: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223718/failed-to-execute-btoa-on-window-the-string-to-be-encoded-contains-characte  link might help you