# Base64 encoding fails for non-latin characters

Tags: javascript, base64

I'm working on a VueJS project where I generate SVG images based on input. After they have been generated, I send data from them to a back end API as a base64 encoded string.

Now, whenever I try to encode the string with UTF8 characters, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
```

I tried to solve the issue with replacing all characters in the HTML with their Unicode code points. However, whenever I try to get the DOM element, the Unicode encoded characters are reverted back to their plain text format.

How can I obtain the HTML as a base64 encoded string?

The issue can be seen in a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/435845/).

I've tried both using `XMLSerializer` and just running `innerHTML.toString()`:

```
let svgEl = this.$el.querySelector('.svg-container svg')
if (!svgEl) {
  console.log('no poster element')
  return
}

// Using XMLSerializer:
console.log(btoa(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(posterEl))

// Using innerHTML:
console.log(btoa(posterEl.innerHTML.toString()))
```

Both the above examples yield the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the answer steps in for this answered question:
[Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223718/failed-to-execute-btoa-on-window-the-string-to-be-encoded-contains-characte)

The key of solution is to encode the string  by this way:

```
btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
```

Comment: unescape were deprecated in JavaScript 1.5
source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp