# converting HTML page into base64

Tags: javascript

I have a fetch request that returns an HTML doc

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>..../body></html>
```

The next thing I'm trying to do is pass it to an API that will let me download it as a PDF

```
fetch("data:application/pdf;base64,"+encoded_data...)
```

I saw that I can use window.btoa() to encode a string into base64. However I'm stuck trying to turn the HTML file into a string, to pass into btoa()

```
fetch("https://www.website.com/cap/people/streamPdf/1214192793"})
.then(resp => {return resp.text()})
.then(data => {
   //this is the HTML file
    var x = String(data)
    console.log(x)
    var base64 = window.btoa(x)
    // console.log(base64)
})
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.
    at <anonymous>:21:25
```

I'm assuming this is because what I'm passing btoa isn't a string?

Comment: How exactly are you stuck trying to turn the HTML file into a string?

Comment: updated my question to be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the html content with a string and try encoding it with base64.

`btoa() //base64 encoding`
`atob() //base64 decoding`

Comment: yes, that is my question. what am I doing wrong? I thought I was converting it to a string

Comment: @Morgan Allen
Please refer to this!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223718/failed-to-execute-btoa-on-window-the-string-to-be-encoded-contains-characte

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question?

```
fetch("https://example.com")
.then(response => {
    return response.text()  
})
.then(html => {
    return window.btoa(html)
})
.then(base64 => {
    return "data:text/html;base64," + base64
})
.then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})
```