# How to download exported excel from laravel using axios?

Tags: javascript, laravel, axios

I have my code below from Backend that is working fine when I test it using *Laravel's blade*. But I can't do the same in using Axios in my React frontend (see frontend code below).

```
return (new NewsExport())->download($filename);
```

I somehow found some solutions from another site: they change the backend code, they use the `Storage` method to return a link instead of a file. But I don't want to use `Storage`, I want to prevent overstoring files (in case of a user in the frontend rapidly clicks the download button).

My question how can we download the returned file from the backend in the frontend Axios?

---

My frontend codes *(the codes below successfully download an excel file, but the file is corrupted I think because I can't open it when I test it using Microsoft Excel)*

```
let response = await newsApi.exportNewsList(payload).then(response => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'exc.xlsx'); //or any other extension
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
});
```

Here is the `response.data` when I log: [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/14nokkr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forgot to specify your `responseType` as **blob** in your api options.

```
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    responseType: 'blob', <=== you need this one
    data: formData,
    url: '/yourApi',
};

return API.request(options);
```

Comment: thanks this solved my problem. But now my new problem is to convert **blob** back to **json** when there is error (validation messages from backend).

Answer (score 0):

It might be to do with how you are converting the response to a blob.
Here is a block of code that I always use when I have to do something like this. I have formatted it to suit your code above so hopefully it will work the same way

```js
const b64toBlob = (b64Data, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
  return blob;
};

let response = await newsApi.exportNewsList(payload).then(response => {
  const dataBlob = b64toBlob(
    response.data,
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64'
  );
  const link = window.document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(dataBlob);
  link.download = 'exc.xlsx';
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
});
```

Comment: i got error **Unhandled Rejection (InvalidCharacterError): Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.**

Comment: That probably means there is something in the spreadsheet that isn't formatted the way it wants. I found this link to another SO question that might solve the error you got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23223718/failed-to-execute-btoa-on-window-the-string-to-be-encoded-contains-characte

Comment: I tried to download in Laravel Blade view. and it downloads successfully, and the file also opened in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: I wonder if the axios is returning the right info then

Comment: here is the `response.data` when I log it https://prnt.sc/14nokkr

Comment: That to me looks like you are actually returning the excel file rather than the excel data