# How to generate a Excel Sheet from Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, excel

How can we generate an Excel sheet using data of an Json object and generate a Pop up window for download.

Comment: simply serve a TSV or CSV or plain HTML table under an an excel mime type. downloadify and others can build the download without a server.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126453/html-table-to-excel-javascript/17129220#17129220

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Excel Builder](http://excelbuilderjs.com/) framework which works fine in Firefox not sure about IE 9...

Probably something like this....

```
var jsonData = [
    ['junk', 'data', 'for'],
    ['generating', 'excel', 'in'],
    ['java', 'script', ' ']
    ];

require(['excel-builder.js/excel-builder', 'download'], function (EB, downloader) {
    var JSworkBook = EB.createWorkbook();
    var JSworkSheet = JSworkBook.createWorksheet({name: 'Sheet'});

    JSworkSheet.setData(jsonData); 

    JSworkBook.addWorksheet(JSworkSheet);

    var data = EB.createFile(JSworkBook);
    downloader('Artist WB.xlsx', data);
});
```

You can generate file download using downloadify

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
Downloadify.create('domElementId',{
    filename: function(){
        return //The filename
    },
    data: function(){
        return EB.createFile(workbook)
    },
    swf: 'path/to/media/downloadify.swf',
    downloadImage: 'path/to/images/download.png',
    width: 100,
    height: 30,
    transparent: true,
    append: false
});
</script>
```

Comment: IE has some issues..