# javascript - table to pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, html-table

I'm using the code in here to convert an html table to excel:

[HTML Table to Excel Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126453/html-table-to-excel-javascript)

To have styles on the excel, I'm converting all my css styles to inline and it works fine.

Now, I'll be needing to export the same into PDF this time.  Any ideas how can this be accomplished?

Comment: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.Demos.Tables has various examples of tables with css both inline as well as in external references

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this library: https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Edit:
I just tried it with a table but it didn't work. It seems it's only suitable for very basic HTML.

Comment: I also found the built in support for tables in jsdpf very limited and buggy. The [AutoTable plugin](https://github.com/someatoms/jsPDF-AutoTable) makes it a lot easier though.