# html table format data to Excel format

Tags: html, excel, html-table, valueconverter

I tried a html page with tables.. I want to convert that table data into an Excel format... I tried search but did not find any good references.. please help me with some good references..

This is  sample table in my html page. The table contains some rows and columns how  is it possible to convert this table values to a Excel format?

```
 <table border="1" id="1.1.3b" name="1.1.3b"> 
  <tr style="background-color:#D8A455; border-top-color: white; border-style: hidden hidden groove;">
  <td colspan="7" style="border-right-style: hidden; font-weight:bold;"> 1.3.4 (b) As per Category of Cities<td></tr>
 <tr><th>&nbsp; </th>
 <th>Tier 1</th>
 <th>Tier 2</th>
 <th>Tier 3</th>
 <th>Tier 4</th>
 <th>Tier 5</th>
 <th>Tier 6</th>
 <th>Total</th></tr>

<tr><td>At the beginning of the year</td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_1_1" name="1.1.3b_1_1" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_1_2" name="1.1.3b_1_2" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_1_3" name="1.1.3b_1_3" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_1_4" name="1.1.3b_1_4" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_1_5" name="1.1.3b_1_5" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_1_6" name="1.1.3b_1_6" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_1_7" name="1.1.3b_1_7" title="qry"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr><td>Closed during the year</td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_2_1" name="1.1.3b_2_1" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_2_2" name="1.1.3b_2_2" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_2_3" name="1.1.3b_2_3" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_2_4" name="1.1.3b_2_4" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_2_5" name="1.1.3b_2_5" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_2_6" name="1.1.3b_2_6" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_2_7" name="1.1.3b_2_7" title="qry"></td>
  </tr>

 <tr><td>Merged during the year</td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_3_1" name="1.1.3b_3_1" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_3_2" name="1.1.3b_3_2" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_3_3" name="1.1.3b_3_3" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_3_4" name="1.1.3b_3_4" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_3_5" name="1.1.3b_3_5" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_3_6" name="1.1.3b_3_6" title="qry"></td>
<input type=text id="1.1.3b_3_7" name="1.1.3b_3_7" title="qry"></td>
</tr>


 <tr><td>Opened during the year</td>

   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_4_1" name="1.1.3b_4_1" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_4_2" name="1.1.3b_4_2" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_4_3" name="1.1.3b_4_3" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_4_4" name="1.1.3b_4_4" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_4_5" name="1.1.3b_4_5" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_4_6" name="1.1.3b_4_6" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_4_7" name="1.1.3b_4_7" title="qry"></td>
 </tr>     

<tr><td>Total at the end of the year</td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_5_1" name="1.1.3b_5_1" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_5_2" name="1.1.3b_5_2" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_5_3" name="1.1.3b_5_3" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_5_4" name="1.1.3b_5_4" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_5_5" name="1.1.3b_5_5" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_5_6" name="1.1.3b_5_6" title="qry"></td>
   <input type=text id="1.1.3b_5_7" name="1.1.3b_5_7" title="qry"></td>
</tr>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126453/html-table-to-excel-javascript check this.

Comment: can i need to insert that code to my script tag

Comment: if you don't need database access, read and follow the post. It implemented by javascript.

Comment: i am using database......

Comment: input data -> store to database -> some operation -> result excel download  // if you using jsp try to POI(https://poi.apache.org/)