# Submitting dynamic table into excel using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have created Dynamic Table for adding and deleting rows using HTML and JavaScript.
How to submit or export  the dynamic data into excel sheet by using javaScript please give me help.

Here is my code..

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }
            }
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
        <INPUT type="button" value="Submit" />


    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
            <TD>Employee Name</TD>
            <TD><input type="text"name="ename"/></TD>
            <TD>Employee Id</TD>
        <TD><input type="text"name="eid"/></TD>
            <TD>Employee Date of Joining</TD>
        <TD><input type="date" name="edoj"/></TD>
            <TD>Employee Designation</TD>
            <TD>
                <SELECT name="edesignation">
                    <OPTION value="aset">Assistant Software Engineer Trainee</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="ase">Assistant Software Engineer</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="asse">Assistant Systems Engineer</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="asa">Assistant Systems Analyst</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="ita">IT Analyst</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="eng">Engineer</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="se">Software Engineer</OPTION>
            <OPTION value="sse">Systems Engineer</OPTION>
                </SELECT>
            </TD>
            <TD>Employee Salary</TD>
            <TD><input type="text"name="esalary"/></TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126453/html-table-to-excel-javascript

Comment: I have tried with that example but not getting result