# Export dynamically generated table to Excel

Tags: javascript, html, excel, html-table

I have a `html table` that adds the row data **`dynamically`** by taking user input. How can I export this table data to excel?

```js
  function fnExcelReport() {
          var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
          var html = table.outerHTML;
          var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + escape(html);
          html table into url 
          elem.setAttribute("href", url);
           elem.setAttribute("download","export.xls");
           return false;
  }
```

```html
    Name:<input type="text" id="name">
    Age:<input type="text" id="age">
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()">
    <table id="myTableData"  border="1px" cellpadding="2">
       <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><b>Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Age</b></td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    <a href="#" id="test" onClick="javascript:fnExcelReport();">download</a>
```

i am able to add the rows but unable to download the excel file. Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Table to Excel Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126453/html-table-to-excel-javascript)

Comment: Check this SO answer for basically the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17129220/79677

Comment: does  above questions solve you problem or you still need answer

Comment: yeah got it.Thankyou