# How can I give name to a file I exported to Excel from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

Similar to: [How can I export tables to excel from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524143/how-can-i-export-tables-to-excel-from-a-webpage).

There is just one little problem. The .xls file is being saved with a random name. But I need to set my own name to the Excel file. Is there any way of doing it?

This is the JavaScript I am using:

```
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'+document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need server side code for that. 
Except in chrome you can use `<a download="abc.xls" />` attribute

Comment: Would that not go to the server as well?

Comment: @mplungjan nop. try it without server.(plain html in a folder)

Comment: it will try to get the stream from href attribute, name the file as in download attribute and let you download.

Comment: Cool. sounds like what OP needs

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with client-side JavaScript, you need to set the response header...

**.NET**

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=filename.xls")
```

**Php**

```
$filename = 'somehting.xls';

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
```

Comment: I told you and the beginning of my comment that its not possible with Javascript because you need to set a response header.