# export html file to excel using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel

Can anybody help me I am a beginner and have no concept how the conversion can be made.

Here is my code:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Charset = "";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
fuFile.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString().Replace("&amp;nbsp;", "").Replace("&amp;", "&"));
Response.End();
```

Is this not enough to export an HTML file to Excel?

Comment: What are you trying to export? Data in the html file?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to upload a file (`fuFile`), and render its contents back to the user in Excel format?  If that's true, update your question with what you are attempting to do and we can guide you to a workable solution.

Comment: i am trying to let the user upload a html file and then convert it into Excel file on button click event.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this works:

```
String content = "<html><body><table><tr><td>your table</td></tr></table></body></html>";

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + ".xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); // not necessarily required
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Output.Write(content);
Response.End();
```

As long as your content is well-formed HTML, this should work.
Also note that comments, VBA code/macros, and multiple work-sheets do not work with this method.  Additionally any styling that is not inline will also not render.

And some other considerations on this matter:

[How can I export tables to excel from a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524143/how-can-i-export-tables-to-excel-from-a-webpage)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ankurmalik123/export-html-to-excel-and-more/