# How to export html table content into spreadsheet?

Tags: html, cross-browser, spreadsheet

How to convert a html table content into an excel spreadsheet?

I got lot of codes there which are good in Chrome but not in Mozilla?

I need a browser compatible code for exporting html table content into spreadsheet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524143/how-can-i-export-tables-to-excel-from-a-webpage

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSV format to export data to Excel which support CSV format.

```
function array2csv(array &$array)
{
   if (count($array) == 0) {
     return null;
   }
   ob_start();
   $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
   fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
   foreach ($array as $row) {
      fputcsv($df, $row);
   }
   fclose($df);
   return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Then use this export function

```
function download_send_headers($filename) {
    // disable caching
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download  
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    // disposition / encoding on response body
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}
```

This is the way you can export information to CSV format. Which is easily to open in Excel.