# Is there any way to set safe content on a excel file generated from js?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, excel

This is the function that I use to generate my excel file .xls

```
 var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel ;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(table, name) {
     if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
     var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
     window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
})() 

tableToExcel('table', 'Table Title')
```

And this is the error I get

[image: Error]

Comment: have you check the problem that the error implies?  extension .xls and the contenttype  does it match or have you set them in the wrong way?

Comment: is it me or the code will create XLSX file not XLS

Comment: @Proof: The code creates a mixture of `HTML` and embedded `XML` if the `Office`version is greater than or equal 9 `<!--[if gte mso 9]>`. `Excel` will accept this mixture as `*.xls` file and parse the mixture to create a workbook from it. But it will throw that warning. There are `JavaScript` solutions in the wild which can really creeate `XLS` and/or `XLSX`. Search keywords: `javascript create excel xls xlsx`.

Comment: that's not an error, it's a warning, and it should not keep the sheet from loading. use CSV output if you want to avoid the warning. and for what it's worth, you don't need all the weird template stuff, a file with just an HTML <table> tag will open in the exact same fashion...

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524143/how-can-i-export-tables-to-excel-from-a-webpage), there you will find all answers.

Answer (score 1):

The following code takes the table and converts it to the **excel** file.

**Note:-** The function have 3rd parameter as the *filename*.

```js
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name, filename) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
      table: table.innerHTML
    }

    document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
    document.getElementById("dlink").click();

  }
})()
```

```html
<table id="newTab">
  <th>Col 1</th>
  <th>Col 2</th>
  <th>Col 3</th>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a id="dlink" style="display:none;"></a>

<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('newTab', 'name', 'newSheet.xls')" value="Table to Excel">
```

The following **Error** might popup while opening the downloaded file.

Error on opening the file. But it opens by clicking 'Yes' anyways.

[image: Error on opening the file. But it opens by clicking 'Yes' anyways.]

And the file opens successfully.

[image: File opens successfully.]