# Is there any way to change the Excel file name Generated using jQuery ?

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel

**Hi, 
I am exporting my data to Excel using jQuery like this:**

```
 window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=dvData]').html()));
```

**Is there any way to change the file name?
Please Help.**

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227131/is-there-any-way-to-set-safe-content-on-a-excel-file-generated-from-js/35473625#35473625) for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354261/how-to-change-the-name-of-file-while-exporting-data-to-excel

Comment: Yes , I got one solution but thats not workinh in Mozilla.  Here is the link : http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/tag/javascript/