# Exporting table to Excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer

I was able to create the XLS file using JavaScript using Active X controls.

For IE I did the following :

```
    var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    objExcel.visible = false; 
    var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add; 
    var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1); 
    objWorksheet.Paste; 
    objExcel.visible = true;
```

But to use ActiveX controls I need to go to Internet Option -> Security ->Custom Level ->Enable  Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting . After enabling this only I am able to create the XLS file.

Is there any other way to create the XLS file in IE-11 apart from active X
I tried to use the following

```
var vDiv = document.getElementById('dvData');
                    vDiv.innerHTML = vTable;
                    var url='data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#dvData').html()) ;
```

but its not working in IE-11. I need to use pure javascript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need to do it in pure javascript, then ActiveX is not the way to go!

Comment: @Endless : Which way can i do this . I am very new to JS and I am having a feeling that without Active X we cannot create XLS on IE-11. Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to [convert the table to a way that excel can understand it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524143/how-can-i-export-tables-to-excel-from-a-webpage)
Expecting a html code to work out of the box in excel is wrong.

Once you got the data in the right format you should create a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) and download that, one good lib to help out with saving blob is [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

```
var chunk = '<?xml version="1.0"?>...'
var blob = new Blob([chunk], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'})
saveAs(blob, 'filename.xls') // using FileSaver.js
```

Comment: Thank you Endless I was able to create the XLS file i wanted .