# Format text when copied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string-formatting, copy-paste

I was wondering if it was possible to format text when it is copied/selected so the content of a `<table>` could be formatted to fit a `csv` format i.e. separate every cell by a comma?

If so, how do you proceed to do that?
I thought of using Regex, but my data can be very complex

Found nothing on the web on this.
You are welcome to use **jQuery** and **JavaScript`**.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
 <td>Traverse Avant de Bas</td>
 <td>2016/08/18 à 08:19:05</td>
 <td>Omal</td>
 <td>1.01-BQ</td>
 <td>BOYLSTON 27D</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Traverse Avant de Bas</td>
 <td>2016/08/18 à 08:19:05</td>
 <td>Omal</td>
 <td>1.01-BQ</td>
 <td>BOYLSTON 27D</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Traverse Avant de Bas</td>
 <td>2016/08/18 à 08:19:05</td>
 <td>Omal</td>
 <td>1.01-BQ</td>
 <td>BOYLSTON 27D</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Traverse Avant de Bas</td>
 <td>2016/08/18 à 08:19:05</td>
 <td>Omal</td>
 <td>1.01-BQ</td>
 <td>BOYLSTON 27D</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you copy this table you end up with a lot of space between each data.

### EDIT

Even though the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5779101/3229805) provided by [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) anwser my specific problem, i am still wondering how one could  format a copied string.

Comment: Use this to copy js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript after date use each to format

Comment: If you select that table and paste it into Excel, it will make a spreadsheet for you. When I save it I get three rows of semicolon separated data - if your separator is comma, you will get a comma separated file

Comment: @mplungjan When i pasted my `<table>` with actual data it didn't worked in Excel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524143/how-can-i-export-tables-to-excel-from-a-webpage

Comment: @mplungjan this is perfect! I already use Datatable and i did'nt know about this option. You should add your comment as an answer so i can mark it as accepted

Comment: I did one better :)

Comment: @mplungjan While this address my problem, i'm curious on how i could format the copied string? Post edited

Comment: Perhaps on click or mousedown? Clone the table and format

Comment: @mplungjan I know it is possible to capture right-click with `mousedown`, but how do you send formatted information when the right menu option is copy. `ctrl-c` would be easier though. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22581382/3229805) which explain how to create a `button` that copy content in the clipboard. Same logic for `ctrl-c`

Answer (score 1):

what about using css ? https://jsfiddle.net/maky/c3dhn5mj/1/

```
td:after {
content: ", ";
}
```

Comment: The idea is good, but when i make the comma transparent they disapear for good (cannot paste them back)... any idea on how to fix this. I cannot display comma on my webpage (boss doesn't want to)