# Export to excel that works from IE 8 to11 using Javascript with open, save, saveas dialog

Tags: javascript, excel

I would like to know if any one has inputs on how I can export a `html` table to excel on client side that works in **IE 8** to **IE 11**.

I tried:

```
var blob = new Blob(table], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8;' });   
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob , 'Export.xls');
```

But, this works only in **IE 11** as the `Blob constructor` is not supported in **IE 8**.

Also tried:

```
var sa = txtArea1.contentWindow.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "IE Excel Export.xls");
```

But this one doesn't show the `Open`, `Save` and `Save as` dialog.

Please suggest on any other option I can use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I export tables to excel from a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524143/how-can-i-export-tables-to-excel-from-a-webpage)

Comment: Thank you, but not much helpfull

Comment: any more comments ?